# different language on title page for \today

Tags: babel, languages

I would like to change the language for the command \today on the title page to german, while the rest of the document is supposed to be in english, such as the contents and bibliography. Using \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} translates these words into german too. So the desired result is the following:
Hamburg, den 2. Februar 2018

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}    
%%%  Titlepage                             
\begin{center}
  Name of the thesis\par
  Hamburg, den \today   
\end{center}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\chapter{Another chapter}  
\section{A section}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
```

which will load German and English, using by default the last one, and then

```
{\selectlanguage{ngerman}\today}
```

(in a group) to switch language locally.